# Lack of Permission in Interop.Outlook when sending Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, outlook, office-interop

I have an asp.net application in C# running IIS 7 on Windows 7.

An email is sent out when a certain event occurs, driven by the client user.

The code is as below: I am using Outlook Interop instead of Exchange SMTP server since the smtpClient is being blocked by McAfee and I am not allowed to change McAfee settings.

We have enterprise license for Office including Outlook, so licensing is not an issue.

When trying to send an email, following error is thrown:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80030005): You don't
>   have appropriate permission to perform this operation. at
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass.CreateItem(OlItemType
>   ItemType) at  in <.cs file name>.

IIS application pool is using NetworkService as ProcessModel identity. 
I also checked DCOMCNFG and it has Network service as an authorized user with appropriate permissions.

How can I fix this?

```
    using outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

    outlook.Application olkApp1 = new outlook.Application();

            outlook.MailItem olkMail1 = (outlook.MailItem)olkApp1.CreateItem(outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            outlook.Accounts accounts = olkApp1.Session.Accounts;
            foreach (outlook.Account account in accounts)
            {
                if (account.SmtpAddress == "")
                {
                    olkMail1.To = toEmail;
                    if (ccEmail != null)
                    {
                        olkMail1.CC = ccEmail;
                    }
                    olkMail1.Subject = subjEmail;
                    olkMail1.Body = bodyEmail;
                    //olkMail1.Attachments.Add(filePath, outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, "attachment");
                    olkMail1.Save();
                    olkMail1.SendUsingAccount = account;
                    ((outlook._MailItem)olkMail1).Send();
```

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: Licensing is the least of your problems. Office Interop is meant to automate one of the Office desktop products. It uses technologies which assume that the product is running in a Desktop environment, which is very, very, different from the server environment. For instance, synchronization  in the desktop environment is by Windows messages sent to a message queue. This is not present in a server environment. You have made a horrible mistake and will regret it bitterly if you do not change your implementation.

Comment: You will see bug after baffling bug, and you will think you have fixed them, but you will simply be moving the bug to a different set of circumstances. This is because the true bug is that you are using Office Interop in a server application, and you didn't fix that one. Take it from my experience.

Comment: Yes, but would not it use the Outlook from the client user's machine to send email?

Comment: No.The server can't reach into the client machine to run programs. That would be a severe security problem.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook cannot be used from a service (such as IIS). Outlook was never designed to work from a service; it can and will display user prompts that no user will be able to dismiss.

Your options are

1. Extended MAPI, but it is only accessible from the C++ or Delphi
2. Exchange Web Services - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx
3. [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) (I am its author) - it is an Extended MAPI wrapper that can be used from a service in any language including C#, VB.Net or VB script:

Comment: In addition, there will be synchronization problems because you will have multiple threads accessing code that is meant to be used by one thread at a time. In the Desktop version of Outlook, that synchronization would have occurred through the message loop. There will be no message loop in your server code. Also, Outlook on the desktop expects one user at a time. Each request to your web site could be from a different user.

Comment: The bottom line is that you are violating the assumptions made by the creators of the software.  They didn't write their code to work in the environment you're using it in, and they didn't _test_ their code to work in that environment. In general, code that is not tested does not work.

Comment: Multiple threads are fine since Outlook is an out-of-proc COM server and all COM calls are marshaled to its main thread. Multithreading is only a problem when the code is running inside the outlook.exe address space, which only applies to Outlook COM add ins and Outlook VBA.

Comment: Also, Outlook can run a message loop when launched from a service, that is not a problem.

Comment: Dmitry, I was talking about the OP's situation, of running Outlook Interop in a server application. In _that_ environment, there is no message loop. Are you suggesting that Outlook _creates_ a message loop when called from a service? And what happens when multiple threads access Interop code at the "same time"?

Comment: John, yes, that what I meant as well - keep in mind that outlook.exe starts up as a regular process, it just runs in a session that has no visible desktop and has security context different from when it is started by an end user. It is perfectly fine for an app in that context to have a message loop.

Comment: Ok, and are you telling me that if I create an ASP.NET web application, and call on Outlook Interop, that requests from all threads (possibly simultaneously) will be marshalled into the message loop of that started process? Because, if so, that's different from the situation I've seen in the past with Office applications. Is that a feature of the 2013 versions of Office, and does it apply to all Office applications, and not just Outlook?

Comment: Yes, that is how it will work. This is not really Outlook specific, just the way out-of-proc calls are marshaled to the COM server.

Comment: Thank you very much Dmitry. That tells me that the issues I had with Excel Interop a decade ago were not related to synchronization. I now believe they were still related to "don't violate the assumptions with which the code was written", but that they were not specifically synchronization issues.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I am a newbie and hence looking for guidance.
I was thinking that when a client browser user clicks on a button that updates the back-end DB and also sends an email to the stakeholders informing of the action. Would that email not go thru that client's Outlook?
That's really what I am hoping to achieve.

For what is it worth, it works when I am debugging the code. So I was thinking it was a permission issue, where NETWORK SERVICE does not have the right permissions. And I made sure that it was added to DCOMCNFG.

Comment: If you need to pop up a new message window on the client, just use the mailto url - you will be able to specify the recipients, subject and message body.